# I get the error: "cast to smaller integer type 'int' from 'string' (aka 'char *')" referencing line of code: while (isalpha(residents[i].name) == 0)

Tags: arrays, c, string, cs50, do-while

Please note that the error I am receiving is "cast to smaller integer type 'int' from 'string' (aka 'char *')" referencing line of code: while (isalpha(residents[i].name) == 0). What I am trying to do in that line of code is check to make sure each character in my string is alphabetical.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int apt;
} tenant;

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    do
    {
        n = get_int("Enter the number of residents: ");
    } while (isalpha(n) != 0 || isspace(n) != 0);

    printf("\n");

    tenant residents[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            residents[i].name = get_string("Enter the residents name: ");
        } while (isalpha(residents[i].name) == 0)

        do
        {
            residents[i].apt = get_int("Enter the residents apt#: ");
        } while (isalpha(residents[i].apt) != 0);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%s resides at %i\n", residents[j].name, residents[j].apt);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `isalpha()` takes a single `int` argument, which is the value of a single character.  You're trying to pass it a `string`, which is presumably a `char *` (it's not standard C, but is a cs50 type).  The `string` typedef was a bad idea.  It would be better to use `char *`, if in fact that's what it is.  But they probably want you to use `string`.

Comment: `isalpha` and `isspace` don't do what you expect them to do. You are using these functions incorrectly everywhere. My guess is that you should just remove all of them together with the do-while loops, but it is hard to tell without knowing what your assignment says exactly. (No, you should NOT check that all characters in a name are alphabetical, ever. This is not how people's names work.)

Comment: `while (isalpha(n) != 0 || isspace(n) != 0)` is probably much more readable as `while (isalpha(n) || isspace(n))`. Also do you really want your `main` function to return `1` on a successful completion?

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I'm new to coding and am trying to implement a simple program on my own, that prompts the user the number of residents in an apt complex, the prompts the user to enter the names and apt numbers of each resident. My code is all over the place now but I appreciate you all helping me on my journey to mastery!